# Define a window over consecutive rows with a particular value

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

**EDIT 2** The Solution to memorize is `count( <GROUP-START-COND> or null ) over ( order by <SORTING> ) AS groupnr` when what you have is a table sorted by `<SORTING>`, new groups of rows are signalled by `<GROUP-START-COND>`, and you need a counter that increases with every group of rows and remains constant throughout the group.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Given a table like this:

```
╔════════╤═══════╤═══════╤════════════════════════════════════...
║ linenr │ level │  key  │ value                              ...
╠════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════════════════════════════...
║      9 │     1 │ title │ Text processing umbrella: Parse / T...
║     10 │     1 │ tags  │ text-processing typesetting markdow...
║     11 │     1 │ about │ unified is an interface for process...
║     12 │     2 │ ...   │ and rehype, but it also allows for ...
║     13 │     1 │ note  │ EXAMPLE                            ...
║     16 │     1 │ tags  │ foo bar baz                        ...
║     17 │     1 │ tags  │ ctx/tag spaceships/orville         ...
...
```

How could I define a `window` that allows me `array_agg`regate over all `value`s that belong to the same group, where a group is defined as rows with adjacent `linenr`s where the first row has `level = 1` and a `key`, and the following lines have `level = 2` and `key = '...'` (using only one of these conditions is sufficient).

I'm trying to come up with a formulation involving `over ( ... rows between current row ... )` but got stuck; maybe numbering the groups first and the aggregate over group numbers would be a good solution.

**EDIT** I realized my question was perhaps not the clearest, lacks a working example and was perhaps better posted to dba.stackexchange.com, so for your reference here's the improved version:

---

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I have the following table with data as shown below; `linenr`s are monotonically increasing but not necessarily consecutive; when the `key` field contains an ellipsis `...` that indicates an entry that is continued from above:

```
create table source (
  linenr    integer unique not null,
  key       text not null,
  value     text );

insert into source values
  (  2, 'tags',  'a'          ),
  (  3, '...',   'b'          ),
  (  4, 'title', 'The Title'  ),
  (  5, 'note',  'this is'    ),
  (  6, '...',   'an EXAMPLE' ),
  (  8, 'title', 'over'       ),
  (  9, '...',   'three'      ),
  ( 10, '...',   'lines'      ),
  ( 11, 'about', 'grouping'   );
```

Now I want to have a view where a group number is assigned based on the content of the `key` field; group numbers do not have to be consecutive but should be distinct for each group of rows that starts with a key other than `...` and continues thru all lines where `key` is `...`, like this:

```
╔════════╤═══════╤═══════╤════════════╗
║ linenr │ group │  key  │   value    ║
╠════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════╣
║      2 │     1 │ tags  │ a          ║
║      3 │     1 │ ...   │ b          ║
║      4 │     2 │ title │ The Title  ║
║      5 │     3 │ note  │ this is    ║
║      6 │     3 │ ...   │ an EXAMPLE ║
║      8 │     4 │ title │ over       ║
║      9 │     4 │ ...   │ three      ║
║     10 │     4 │ ...   │ lines      ║
║     11 │     5 │ about │ grouping   ║
╚════════╧═══════╧═══════╧════════════╝
```

I tried to do this with windows / partitions and the tabibitosan pattern, but haven't been able to come up with anything working; also, using at the preceding row with `lag()` doesn't help where there are multiple consecutive lines with `...`. In a spreadsheet this is an extremely easy thing to do but in SQL I can seemingly not refer to the previous row of the *current* query, can I?

---

**DISCUSSION OF SOLUTION**

Turns out there's a solution so simple it hurts (not to have come up with it on one's own):

```
select
    linenr                              as linenr,
    key                                 as key,
    value                               as value,
    sum( rst ) over ( order by linenr ) as group_nr
  from ( select
    linenr,
    key,
    value,
    case when key != '...' then 1 end   as rst
  from source ) as x;
```

This works because we assign a `1` for lines that start a group and `null` otherwise; then, `sum()`ming over all rows (in the right order) will treat `null`s like zeros which then causes all the group-starting rows to get a new `group_id` and all follow-up rows to keep that count. Simples if you know how...

Credits go to user [McNets](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/110455/mcnets).

This same can be done in a short and memorable one-liner, for which see the above edit and the answer by [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter), below.

**EDIT 2** Commenters rightfully complained about my edited question being really a new question. I think the upshot is that when solving a recalcitrant problem, one should try and find that particular screw that wouldn't turn, and come up with a small-scale model that highlights that particular part and leaves out the other parts. In this case, aggregating over rows with a group number wasn't the hard part for me, it was assigning group numbers; also, "define a window that allows me array_aggregate over all values" wasn't part of the problem, it was part of what I imagined could lead to a solution.

Comment: Your Postgres version and table definition? Assuming `linenr` is defined UNIQUE? Are single rows (no following level 2) considered groups, too?

Comment: Postgres v10 here; I think I answered your questions with my edit.

Comment: You replaced the question with a different one.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter I guess you might say so; I realized both the inclusion of the `level` field and the aggregation step came across as a distraction rather than a clarification. I'll re-edit my question to say that much. Apologies.

Comment: So we can check this one off as *answered*?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer to updated (new) question:

```
SELECT *
     , count(key <> '...' OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY linenr) AS grp
FROM   source;
```

See dupe on dba.SE:

- [How can I assign group IDs depending on content?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197125/how-can-i-assign-group-ids-depending-on-content/197140)

#### Answer to original question:

Assuming current Postgres 10 and `linenr` is defined `UNIQUE`, this would achieve what you describe:

```
SELECT min(linenr) AS lines_from
     , max(linenr) AS lines_to
     , array_agg(value) AS value_arr
FROM  (
   SELECT linenr, level, value
        , count(level = 1 OR NULL) OVER (ORDER BY linenr) AS grp
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY linenr) - linenr    AS adjacent
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY linenr
   ) sub
GROUP  BY grp, adjacent  -- same group, adjacent numbers
HAVING min(level) = 1    -- but only groups that start with level 1 
ORDER  BY lines_from;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/21a1ea/3) with extended test case.

Related, with more explanation:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35380/select-longest-continuous-sequence/35389#35389)

About `count(level = 1 OR NULL)`:

- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Tabibitosan method

```
select array_agg(value) FROM
(
select t.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY linenr ) - 
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN level = 2 and key = '...'
                          THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ORDER BY linenr ) as chg
FROM   Table1 as t
  ) as a 
  WHERE (level,key)  <> ( 2,'...')
  GROUP BY chg
  ORDER BY chg;
```

Comment: I don't think this query achieves what the question asks. Your `row_number() OVER -- 1 or 0` creates exactly two groups. Does not seem to make sense.

Comment: So did I: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/21a1ea/4 "It works", ok. But does it do what the question asks for?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter : I think i may have misunderstood the question. Not clear however if that is the case.

Comment: The question does leave some room for interpretation ... The OP will clarify, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for giving the hint about the tabibitosan method which however doesn't work here or at least not in the way you wrote it down (and I couldn't find another way either) because it doesn't produce a series of 'gaps and islands' if I understand correctly. Instead, there's an ingeniously simple solution that someone just pointed out me here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/197126/126933

Comment: @JohnFrazer : I see that the question is now completely changed and this answer is not relevant anymore. I suggest you to chose to implement the latest  answer by Erwin Brandstetter, using `count(..) over (ORDER BY)` ,rather than the one you are referring to. I would have provided the same answer if I had understood your real question!